# Placeholder text not centered in iOS

Tags: ios, swift

I have created text field with Rounded Corners. All is good with the position of the cursor and also when i type the text. But the Placeholder text is off. Is there a way for the placeholder position to follow the Text field.

Below code overrides from the UITextField functions to reposition the cursor.

```
override func textRect(forBounds bounds: CGRect) -> CGRect {
    return CGRect(x: 0 + textOffset,
                  y: 0 + (textOffset / 2),
                  width: self.frame.width - textOffset,
                  height: self.frame.height + textOffset)
}

override func editingRect(forBounds bounds: CGRect) -> CGRect {
    return CGRect(x: 0 + textOffset,
                  y: 0 + (textOffset / 2),
                  width: self.frame.width - textOffset,
                  height: self.frame.height + textOffset)
```

[image: This is the offset shown on the image]

Comment: [`placeholderRect(forBounds:)`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uitextfield/1619615-placeholderrect)

Answer (score 1):

Use this override method to set placeholderRect

```
override func placeholderRect(forBounds bounds: CGRect) -> CGRect {
    return UIEdgeInsetsInsetRect(bounds, paddingInsets)
}
```

Comment: Make sure answer is right then right make and upvote. thanks

Comment: Yup this works, but i am still building reputation minimum 15 :) before i can upvote. But have upvoted it and it is just not shown publicly yet.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `attributedPlaceholder` paragraph styles you can center the placeholder in a UITextField.

```
let textField = UITextField(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 100, width: self.view.frame.size.width, height: 60))
textField.backgroundColor = UIColor.gray
let centeredParagraphStyle = NSMutableParagraphStyle()
centeredParagraphStyle.alignment = .center
let attributedPlaceholder = NSAttributedString(string: "Placeholder", attributes: [NSAttributedStringKey.paragraphStyle: centeredParagraphStyle])
textField.attributedPlaceholder = attributedPlaceholder
```

Comment: Did you try this solution ?

Answer (score 0):

What worked for me was creating `baselineOffset` attribute and then setting the `attributedPlaceholder`.

```
    let attributes = [NSAttributedString.Key.baselineOffset : NSNumber(2.0)]

myTextField.attributedPlaceholder = NSAttributedString(string: "Placeholder", attributes: attributes)
```